# Drag Drop for Files AND also Folders

Tags: wpf, winapi, drag-and-drop

So I looked at this link before:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/10/26/creating-something-from-nothing-developer-friendly-virtual-file-implementation-for-net.aspx

The class works flawlessly for Files, but it doesn't support directory's etc, does anyone have any idea how I can change the class to support it, I"m no pinvoke whiz. I've tried a million different things, overriding some code to do File Copy and Directory creation of my drop source into the TEMP directory and attempting to trigger a FileDrop, but this locks up the app entirely.

This leads me to believe that there must be a better way to enable directory structure creation as well.

Comment: *I've tried a million different things*... please show us some.

Comment: Can you show how you're creating your `FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR` structures?

Answer (score 1):

The main part of the Drag and Drop operation is the `DragDrop.DoDragDrop` method. From the [`DragDrop.DoDragDrop` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dragdrop.dodragdrop.aspx) page on MSDN:

```
public static DragDropEffects DoDragDrop(
    DependencyObject dragSource,
    Object data,
    DragDropEffects allowedEffects
)
```

Of particular interest is the `data` parameter:

> A data object that contains the data being dragged.

Notice how this parameter is of type `Object`, so it's completely up to *you* as to what object you use in the operation. Now I'm not sure what code you found from the page that you linked to, but if I were trying to drag and drop files and folders, I wouldn't need special classes to do it for me.

The simplest way to do that is to just pass the file and/or folder paths instead of the actual data. The control that the data is dropped on can access the data using the file paths just as easily as the drag source. You should be able to locate the `DragDrop.DoDragDrop` method from your code and easily adapt that code.

If you want to do Drag and Drop operations in the correct way, then I'd recommend that you take a look at the [Drag and Drop Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN. It fully explains what to do and provides several code examples.

Comment: I *think* the op is doing something where the drop target is not a wpf control.  He wants to drag *out* of a wpf app and drop it into a com component; that's only a guess.  If it's the right guess, you'll need to change your answer.  It's a great answer, but to a different question :)

Comment: You *might* be right... that's the problem with users adding links but not discussing what they linked to in their question. I think I'll leave the answer as it may well help people with similar Drag and Drop problems.

Comment: Yes, the question itself needs clarification.  I will add another answer in the same spirit as yours.

Answer (score 1):

To implement drag and drop in MVVM without much experience in WPF, you can refer to 5 steps; I will outline these...

**Step 1:  Attached Behaviours**

Add a new class to your project called Behaviours.  It should look like this...

```
public static class Behaviours
{
    #region DandBehaviour
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DandBehaviourProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DandBehaviour", typeof(ICommand), typeof(Behaviours),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None,
                OnDandBehaviourChanged));
    public static ICommand GetDandBehaviour(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (ICommand)d.GetValue(DandBehaviourProperty);
    }
    public static void SetDandBehaviour(DependencyObject d, ICommand value)
    {
        d.SetValue(DandBehaviourProperty, value);
    }
    private static void OnDandBehaviourChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid g = d as Grid;
        if (g != null)
        {
            g.Drop += (s, a) =>
                {
                    ICommand iCommand = GetDandBehaviour(d);
                    if (iCommand != null)
                    {
                        if (iCommand.CanExecute(a.Data))
                        {
                            iCommand.Execute(a.Data);
                        }
                    }
                };
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Non grid");
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

This class implements an attached dependency property which can be reached from both your Xaml and your View Model.  It hooks the "Drop" event and invokes a command on it.

**Step 2: Instrument the Xaml**

In this step you need to add the name space to the Xaml so that it can find the behaviours class in Step 1.  It looks something like this...

```
xmlns:b="clr-namespace:DdMvvm"
```

This statement assigns the alias 'b' to the behaviours.  Then you tell the WPF root window to accept drops...

```
AllowDrop="true"
```

Then you can add the behaviour to your logical tree thusly...

```
<Grid AllowDrop="True" b:Behaviours.DandBehaviour="{Binding DandCommand}">
    <DockPanel Background="Bisque" AllowDrop="True"/>
</Grid>
```

**Step 3:  Add command support**

Download Josh Smith's 'Relay Command' from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx  For completeness purposes, it is given here as...

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{   //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
}
```

**Step 4: Write the View Model**

A View Model looks like this...

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand DandCommand { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        DandCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteDandCommand, CanExecuteDandCommand);
    }
    private void ExecuteDandCommand(object obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            IDataObject ido = obj as IDataObject;
            if (ido != null)
            {
                var fileDrop = ido.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true);
                var filesOrDirectories = fileDrop as String[];
                if (filesOrDirectories != null && filesOrDirectories.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (string fullPath in filesOrDirectories)
                    {
                        if (Directory.Exists(fullPath))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(@"{0} is a directory", fullPath);
                        }
                        else if (File.Exists(fullPath))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(@"{0} is a file", fullPath);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(@"{0} is not a file and not a directory", fullPath);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private bool CanExecuteDandCommand(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var handler = System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref PropertyChanged, null, null);
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
```

This VM implements a command (called `DandCommand`) which will be fired by the attached behaviour (remember Step 1?).  The 'juicy part' of the VM is the bit which dereferences the drag-and-drop payload.  In this particular VM, the code dereferences the data and finds out if it is a file or a directory.  It then prints a diagnostic to the console.  You can change this part to load images, or internet links, or what-ever can be dropped.

**Step 5: Wiring the data context**

This is done by different developers in different ways (for industrial apps, lots of people like to use Prism and Unity, but that's ott for a simple how-to like this post).  The most straight-forward approach is to change your View to look like this...

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

This code sets the window's data context to your VM so that the binding can take place.

Those steps give you a good starting point for MVVM and drag-and-drop and getting the whole thing to work.  The big payback in using MVVM for these things is the clean separation and compartmentalisation that you get.  I.e., the VM can be unit-tested without having to instantiate the WPF binding engine.